# В библиотеке "cliche" Build error: ошибка package org.junit does not exist import org.junit.Test;

Tags: java

Проект запускается. Но при Build - выдаёт ошибку:

> /home/aleksandr/NetBeansProjects/StripedTrip/src/asg.cliche/test/asg/cliche/DashJoinedNamerTest.java:10:
>   error: package org.junit does not exist import org.junit.Test;

Помогите собрать проект.

Comment: Добавьте JUnit в зависимости.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил, заработало!
Сделал, так: 1)правой кнопкой на проект,
2) Properties
3) Libraries
4) Add library
5) Import. 
6) JUnit 4.12.
7) Add Library

Comment: ознакомьтесь с правилами этого сайта в разделе справка.